# JQuery Functions loading prematurely

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What my aim here is when a button is pressed, it replaces the content of the div with a textbox and a button. And when the button is pressed, it posts the text to a script, which handles the request and stores the inputted data from the textbox into the database.

It is then set to call another function called `Reset();` which is supposed to restore the old contents of the div. However, the idea that I had in mind it calls the DB Query to find what's CURRENTLY in the database. But, it's not doing that, it's just getting the old value. Which makes me think that the function is running at the start of the page, and not when it is called.

It definitely updates the value because when I refresh the value is updated. Here's my code:

```
<script>

   $(function () {
       $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
           var myVar = <?php echo json_encode($db->result("SELECT * FROM revision_notes", "notes")); ?>;
           $('#WCTarget').html("<div class='span12'><h2>Revision Notes</h2><form id='revisionnotes' name='revisionnotes' method='POST'><textarea style='width:100%;height:290px; padding:10px;' id='notes' name='notes'>" + myVar + "</textarea><br/><button onclick='Button();' name='submit' id='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Change Revision</button></div></form></div>");
       });
   });

   function Reset() {
       var myVar2 = <?php echo json_encode($db->result("SELECT * FROM revision_notes", "notes")); ?>;
       $('#WCTarget').html("<h2>What's new?</h2><div class='well'>" + myVar2 + "</div><input type='button' value='Change Revision' id='button' name='button' class='btn btn-primary'>");
     });

   function Button() {
    $('#revisionnotes').on('submit', function(e) {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'submits/updatenotes.php',
            data: data, // $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                Reset();
                alert("Delta - POST submission succeeded");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}   
</script>
```

Is there any way to stop the function from retrieving the value from the database until it is called from the Success of the `Button` function?

Many thanks, Jarrod.

Comment: Your `Reset()` function uses the `myVar2` variable that is set when the page is first served. You need to use the value from the `data` parameter of your `$.ajax()` success function, and your `updatenotes.php` page needs to return the new value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
       $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
           var myVar = <?php echo json_encode($db->result("SELECT * FROM revision_notes", "notes")); ?>;
           $('#WCTarget').html("<div class='span12'><h2>Revision Notes</h2><form id='revisionnotes' name='revisionnotes' method='POST'><textarea style='width:100%;height:290px; padding:10px;' id='notes' name='notes'>" + myVar + "</textarea><br/><button onclick='Button();' name='submit' id='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Change Revision</button></div></form></div>");
       });
   });
```

this is not "exactly" a function, it is a closure around a piece of code that runs **only once**, onload of page.

If u want to load a changing value from your server, you would need to use AJAX, same as u use for the data submission.